# Add data in Refreshable Listview Android dynamically?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to add dynamic data from web service at the bottom of my list. and the list should refresh when i scrolls down the list to show the older messages..and load next page.. but my code is doing reverse i.e scrolling top to load next page and i am getting the older messages at first.. here is my code.
if someone could help...

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.conversations_activity);
     mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
                int maxLoads = 30;
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {    
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if ((totalItemCount - 1 > maxLoads)&& ((totalItemCount - 1) % maxLoads == 0)) {
                        System.gc();
                    }
                    if (((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) == totalItemCount)
                            && !isDataLoading && isScrollingEnable) {
                        new LoadNextPage(ConversationsActivity.this).execute();
                    }
                }
            });

    new ConversationListTask(ConversationsActivity.this).execute();
}
}
private class ConversationListTask extends BaseAsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        public ConversationListTask(Activity activity) {
            super(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void runDoInBackground() throws RuntimeException, Exception {
            isDataLoading = true;
            isScrollingEnable = false;
            mPageNumber = 0;
            try {
                listMessage = APIProcessor.listMessage(ConversationsActivity.this, "1",
                        mPageNumber);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void runOnPostExecute() {
            isDataLoading = false;
            isScrollingEnable = true;

            convoListAdapter = new ConversationListAdapter(
                    ConversationsActivity.this, listMessage, urlThumbImageLoader);
            mListViewConversation.setAdapter(convoListAdapter);
            mListViewConversation.setSelection(mListViewConversation.getAdapter()
                    .getCount() - 1);

        }
    }
class LoadNextPage extends BaseAsyncTask {

        public LoadNextPage(Activity activity) {
            super(activity);
            setDefaultProgressDialogStatus(false);
            findViewById(R.id.list_loading_view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void runDoInBackground() throws RuntimeException, Exception {
            isDataLoading = true;
            tempList = APIProcessor.listMessage(ConversationsActivity.this, "1",
                    mPageNumber + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void runOnPostExecute() {
            new LoadNextPage(ConversationsActivity.this).execute();
            findViewById(R.id.list_loading_view).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            isDataLoading = false;
            if (tempList == null || tempList.isEmpty() || listMessage == null
                    || listMessage.isEmpty()) {

            }
            else {
                mPageNumber++;
                for (int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++) {
                    listMessage.add(tempList.get(i));
                }
                convoListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are executing LoadNextPage on every postExecute of LoadNextPage task. that seems infinite call to LoadNextPage.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [see this link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/)

May be you miss

```
int currentPosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
lv.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm outlining what I see at your code:
on `ConversationListTask.runOnPostExecute` method you retrieve list items. Create an adapter and set it to your listView. Then you set your list's selection to last item. This triggers a scroll to last element and your scrolledToBottom condition becomes true then `LoadNextPage` task starts immediately. And as I commented on your question, after your first call to `LoadNextPage`, it will create and execute another instance of it on its post execute and repeat it on every post execute which will lead a infinite call.

Firstly, organize your code again. If you don't want to set selection to bottom after setting adapter to your listView, then remove this code from `ConversationListTask.runOnPostExecute`:

```
mListViewConversation.setSelection(mListViewConversation.getAdapter().getCount() - 1);
```

And stop calling LoadNextPage on every postExecute of LoadNextPage task.

*BTW you are correctly listening scrolledToBottom event on `onScroll`. I use a similar `OnScrollListener` implementation and can share if you want.